# How can I use a parent class's member to satisfy an interface in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have the following situation:

```
public interface IStuffer
{
    public string Foo { get; }
}

public class BaseClass
{
    public static string Foo { get { ... } }
}

public class MyClass : BaseClass, IStuffer
{
}
```

This won't build because MyClass needs a Foo member.  How can I use BaseClass's Foo implementation to satisfy MyClass's requirement for Foo?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's because Foo is a static member of the BaseClass. Just take away the static keyword!

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public string Foo { get { ... } }
}
```

**Edit**: Else if you really want it to stay static, you could use an explicit implementation

```
public class MyClass : BaseClass, IStuffer
{
    string IStuffer.Foo { get { return BaseClass.Foo; } }
}
```

Comment: Or, if that is not possible, create a non-static Foo that calls the static Foo to satisfy the requirement.

Comment: +1 As a rule, interfaces cannot be satisfied by static members.

Comment: Thanks.  The second example is what I was looking for.  Just as a side question, what is the accessibility of Foo in MyClass?

Comment: With explicit implementations, it'll not even appear (i.e. less than private) while working with MyClass types explicitly, but "public" when working with IStuffer declared types.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your interface expects a NON-static "string Foo", if you make Foo Non-Static in BaseClass then it will satisfy your Interface :)

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces cannot support static properties or methods. If you have an interface, all methods of that interface must be instance rather than class scope.

Answer (score 0):

In two ways:

**1.** Rename Foo to something else and add a method Foo like this:

```
public class BaseClass
{
 public static string FormerlyCalledFoo { get { ... } }
 public string Foo { get { ... } }
}
```

**2.** If you absolutely must have a static Foo property then you can implement the IStuffer interface as an explicit interface implementation like this:

```
public class BaseClass : IStuffer
{
 public static string Foo { get { ... } }
 string IStuffer.Foo { get { ... } }
}
```

If using the latter method, then you have to be aware that you have to cast instances of BaseClass to IStuffer to access the IStuffer.Foo property